# Summing duplicate rows in pandas dataframe with multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My Pandas dataframe looks like

```
Month/Year col1 col2 col3 col4 
May,2019   13   12    11   33 
June,2019  23   11    16   31 
July,2019  21   14    17   21 
Aug,2019   11   12    13   23 
Aug,2019   10   20    20   20 
Sept,2019  11   23    12   13 
Sept,2019  20   30    10   20
```

I want to sum all the duplicate rows in Month/Year col and with the respective column

```
Month/Year col1 col2 col3 col4
May,2019   13   12    11   33
June,2019  23   11    16   31
July,2019  21   14    17   21
Aug,2019   21   32    33   43
Sept,2019  31   53    22   33
```

I've looked at other examples and tried groupby on Month/Year adding rest of the columns but didn't work

```
df.groupby(['Month/Year'], as_index=False)['col1','col2','col3','col4].sum()
```

Goupby adds up all the columns together for the duplicate record

Comment: What about `df.groupby(['Month/Year'])[['col1','col2','col3','col4]].sum()`?

Comment: `df.groupby(['Month/Year'], as_index=False, sort=False)['col1','col2','col3','col4'].sum()` works for me

Comment: or just `df.groupby('Month/Year').sum()`

Comment: *but didnt work* ...what did not work? Any errors? Or undesired results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
df.groupby('Month/Year', sort=False, as_index=False).sum()
```

Output:

```
  Month/Year  col1  col2  col3  col4
0   May,2019    13    12    11    33
1  June,2019    23    11    16    31
2  July,2019    21    14    17    21
3   Aug,2019    21    32    33    43
4  Sept,2019    31    53    22    33
```

Comment: sort=False makes all the difference ;)

Answer (score 0):

An apostrophe `'` is missing after `col4`.

The below statement is producing the desired output:

```
data.groupby(['Month/Year'])[['col1','col2','col3','col4']].sum()
```

[image: Query with results]